# view.py not updating in Django with wsgi

Tags: django, wsgi

My django application has recently started exhibiting this behaviour in live.
When I check out a new release and expand it into the appropriate directory (replacing the existing version), the new versions of the files are not picked up.
I've tried restarting apache many times and have ps -ef | grepped for rogue apache / wsgi processes, but can't find anything wrong.

If I introduce errors directly into views.py (like changing the spelling of a method) then it doesn't complain, even after restarting the server.
but if I delete views.py altogether, then it does complain that it can't find the file.

The functionality that I've changed is to do with the emailing of some data.
The emailing is still happening whenever I refresh the page, but the formatting that I've introduced is not being invoked.
Also, I've asked it to forward to a new thankyou page, but it's continuing to forward me back to the form. (and still emails the form content)
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you removed all .pyc files that might be left over from the previous versions of your view.py?